# Java package error

Tags: java, simulation

I am currently working on a Java project using openDIS- however, in one of my Java class files, I have started off with the line `package openDIS`, the same as in the other Java class file that I'm using, but in this one for some reason, I get a compiler error that says

```
The type javax.persistence.GenerationType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Any ideas why this is, or how I can resolve it?

The one quick fix it offers is to 'configure build path- clicking this opens a dialog box which shows that I have the 'open-dis_4.08.jar' and 'JRE System Library [JavaSE -1.7]' libraries added to my project... I can't think of any others that I would need...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `javax.persistence` package is part of the [Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html).

You'll need to use the [Java EE SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn) instead of Java SE.

Comment: Ok, I now have Java EE installed, and am using it in Eclipse (I have selected the 'Java EE' tab at the top right of the Eclipse window), but I'm still getting the same problem... any ideas why this is?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, I'm afraid.  But I've got a project referencing `javax.persistence.GenerationType` working in Netbeans using the Java EE SDK & JDK downloaded from the link above.  Is the classpath of your project properly configured?

Comment: It seems I had to add an external JAR to the Java Build Path- which I guess is what you were suggesting in your last comment? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry- one follow up question (hopefully a quick one!) Although it now compiles, when trying to run my EspduReceiver.java class, the program terminates as soon as it starts running, and I get the following message in the console: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/nps/moves/disenum/PduType at ... (PduFactory.java:86)`. It says that this error is occurring at the line `Pdu pdu = pduFactory.createPdu(packet.getData());` but that this is caused by a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException... Does this mean that I will need to import the pduFactory class myself/ import it?

Comment: Ok-it seems I was missing the dis-enums jar file, which had the class that I needed, so just adding that to the build path seemed to sort the issue